# Make Link dynamic or disable link OnClick React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im trying to do some error handling for a search bar that I have. Currently If you try to search something and havent actually typed anything then an alert will popup. However the user will still be redirected to a different page. My 404 currently handles this page.

I want it so that if the user hasnt typed anything they wont be redirect and will stay on the same page.
I have thought of two methods for this.

Either disable the link when the `submitHandler` function is called preventing the redirect.
Or change the pathname of the Link when `submitHandler` is called to keep them on the same page.

I have tried both methods with no luck.

Heres the component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { content } from "../reviews";

export default function Search(props) {
  //For storing and setting search input
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  function submitHandler() {
    if (query.length === 0) {
      alert('Search bar is empty. Please enter a value to search.');
    }
  }

  return (
    //Search input
    <div className="flex flex-col z-10">
      <form
        className="text-black ml-5 py-0.5 lg:py-0 flex border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md bg-white px-1"
      >
        <input
          id="searchInput"
          className="focus:outline-none"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={query}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setQuery(event.target.value);
          }}
        />

        {/* Search Button */}
        {/* Flex container to align the icon and bar */}
        <div className="flex mt-1.5">
          <Link to={{ pathname: "/results/" + query }}>
            <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
              <svg
                className="fill-current h-auto w-4 "
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                {/* ! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. */}
                <path d="M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>

      {/* Search Suggestions */}
      <div className="ml-5 px-0.5">
        {/* Query must have length to prevent mapping by default */}
        {query.length > 0 && content
            //Filter through JSON
            .filter((content) => {
              //If input return object
              if (query === "") {
                return content;
              }

              //If any input characters much object characters return corresponding object
              else if (
                content.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLocaleLowerCase())
              ) {
                return content;
              }

              return null;
            })
            
            //Maps element based on the number of JSON objects
            .map((content) => {
              return (
                <div className="bg-white rounded-sm">
                  <Link to={content.link} onClick={() => setQuery(() => "")}>
                    <p>{content.name}</p>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              );
            })
          };
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the JSON array if relevant

```
export const content = [
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "Elden\nRing", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text1", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text2", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text3", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text4", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text5", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text6", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text7", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text8", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text9", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text10", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
    {link: "/review/elden-ring", name: "text11", image: '../images/elden-ring-thumbnail.jpg', heading: 'text1', text: 'text1'},
];
```

Comment: Which link do you want to have conditional routing on?

Comment: link 37 ``` <Link to={{ pathname: "/results/" + query }}> ```

Comment: Answer posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should useNavigate like this (V6)

Add the following

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
let navigate = useNavigate();

  function submitHandler() {
    if (query.length === 0) {
      alert('Search bar is empty. Please enter a value to search.');
    }else{
         navigate(`/results/${query}`);
     }
  }
```

then remove the link part from the button so it appears like

```
<div className="flex mt-1.5">
          //<Link to={{ pathname: "/results/" + query }}> //delete this line
            <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
               ...
            </button>
          //</Link> //delete this line
        </div>
```

If you are using V5 react router then its just a small change to this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

  function submitHandler() {
    if (query.length === 0) {
      alert('Search bar is empty. Please enter a value to search.');
    }else{
         history.push(`/results/${query}`);
     }
  }
```

Personally I would go with the V6/V5 option for conditional routing as the first option is a bit 'hacky'

Comment: So i went with your V6 solution and it always redirects me to the index page rather than the page I was on is there a way to change that? So instead of ```{query.length === 0 ? "" : `/results/${query}`} ``` alter it ```{query.length === 0 ? "currentPage" : `/results/${query}`}```

Comment: I was also unsure as it what you meant by 'remove the link part from the button'

Comment: @JoshHaywood Changed my answer to make it clearer please check now